# Performance enhancement failed

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask

I have an **ANR (Application is not responding) problem**. I am trying to separate tasks into threads using AsyncTask, however it seems worse than before.

I am doing something wrong but I could not get where is the problem.

[image]

As you can see, the main thread takes 6M milliseconds which is not good I think.

To increase performance, I did those things in `onCreate()` methods of different activities:

```
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO your background code
            if(sPreferenceManager.getBoolean(Constants.SharedPreferences.UPDATE_REQUIRED))
            {

                log(Log.DEBUG,"mediaplayeractivity","UPDATE_REQUIRED");

                mViewModel.getmInteractor().updateDatabaseAfterLogin();
            }
        }
    });

AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO your background code
            initServices(savedInstanceState);

        }
    });



AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Fabric.with(GomusApplication.this, new Crashlytics());

            //TODO your background code
            AndroidThreeTen.init(GomusApplication.this);
            initPreferences();
            sInstance = GomusApplication.this;
            initRealm();
            appComponent =  DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(new 
AppModule(GomusApplication.this)).build();
            appComponent.inject(GomusApplication.this);
        }
    });
```

I separated tasks into **AsyncTasks**. However it made performance worse!

**UPDATE:**
I have changed my AsyncTasks like this but still I do not see any enhancement weirdly:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            if(sPreferenceManager.getBoolean(Constants.SharedPreferences.UPDATE_REQUIRED))
            {

                log(Log.DEBUG,"mediaplayeractivity","UPDATE_REQUIRED");

                mViewModel.getmInteractor().updateDatabaseAfterLogin();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);
```

I also made some layout changes on constraint layouts like some fields were missing and I added them. I deleted some big images to increase the performance.

However, what I did made the performance worse. It was taking 3M milliseconds to run main thread but now it is 6M milliseconds.

I am so sorry, I have never tried to increase performance until now so I do not have enough knowledge. But I have made some research and people say that use AsyncTask.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that the correct way to use `AsyncTask` anyways? Shouldn't you put your code inside `doInBackground()` inside an AsyncTask object instead?

Comment: Also when you execute the AsyncTask object, make sure you pass in AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR to make sure it gets executed on a different thread parallel to the main one.

Comment: I am not sure if it is correct. I saw some posts that people were suggesting to use this way. I added the THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR flag but still not sure where to add doInBackground() in the AsyncTask object.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Note that, however, you do not need to create a separate class for it, you could anonymously execute one on the run ;)

Comment: And https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)

Comment: @mohkamfer I have changed my asynctasks and updated my post with the new ones. However it did not make any enhancement about the performance.